# iphone app information page

Tags: iphone

What is the best way of displaying an information page in an iphone app? Anny ideas will be very helpful. I would prefer to keep all info within iphone app so as not to make it internet connectivity dependant..

Comment: Please take a moment to go through your old questions and mark them answered, where people took the time to help you out.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realise I could do this. I can't seem to find a way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up a "home" view controller as the root view controller of a navigation controller.

From here, set up a button or tab to trigger pushing an "information" view controller onto the navigation stack.

In the "information" view controller, use a `UITableView` to organize sections and table cells that drill down to further details.